# Alfresco: jsonUtils.toObject() fails with NullPointer or EcmaError/TypeError

Tags: json, alfresco

I try to use the **jsonUtils.toObject** method with a json string or a json object as parameter in the javascript console in Alfresco Enterprise 4.1.5, and getting the following errors.

Reference:

> http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.enterprise.doc%2Freferences%2Fapi-ws-obj-jsonUtils.html
>
> toObject(jsonString) Takes a JSON string and converts it to a native
>   JavaScript object.
>
> toObject(jsonObject) Takes a JSON object and converts it to a native
>   JavaScript object.

**Test 1**

```
var jsonString = '{"test": "test"}';
logger.log( jsonUtils.toObject(jsonString) );
```

Error:

```
500 Internal Error
An error inside the HTTP server which prevented it from fulfilling the request.
10080038 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 10080143 Failed to execute script 'Javascript Console Script': 10080142 TypeError: Cannot find default value for object. (fb91e06fb1303a88bc57085eaaf9692f.js#2)

Wrapped Exception (with status template): 10080063 Failed to execute script 'Javascript Console Script': 10080062 TypeError: Cannot find default value for object. (b7b11bfd779a718cabdce9ea9162012f.js#5)
 org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException: 10080013 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 10080063 Failed to execute script 'Javascript Console Script': 10080062 TypeError: Cannot find default value for object. (b7b11bfd779a718cabdce9ea9162012f.js#5)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:1067)
    at de.fme.jsconsole.ExecuteWebscript.executeScriptContent(Unknown Source)
    at de.fme.jsconsole.ExecuteWebscript.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at de.fme.jsconsole.ExecuteWebscript$2.execute(Unknown Source)
    at de.fme.jsconsole.ExecuteWebscript$2.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:401)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:291)
    at de.fme.jsconsole.ExecuteWebscript.runWithTransactionIfNeeded(Unknown Source)
    at de.fme.jsconsole.ExecuteWebscript.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at de.fme.jsconsole.ExecuteWebscript$1.doWork(Unknown Source)
    at de.fme.jsconsole.ExecuteWebscript$1.doWork(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:529)
    at de.fme.jsconsole.ExecuteWebscript.runScriptWithTransactionAndAuthentication(Unknown Source)
    at de.fme.jsconsole.ExecuteWebscript.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:365)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:517)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:333)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:377)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:132)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:465)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.alfresco.scripts.ScriptException: 10080063 Failed to execute script 'Javascript Console Script': 10080062 TypeError: Cannot find default value for object. (b7b11bfd779a718cabdce9ea9162012f.js#5)
    at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:202)
    at org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.execute(ScriptServiceImpl.java:212)
    at org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.executeScript(ScriptServiceImpl.java:174)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryScriptProcessor.executeScript(RepositoryScriptProcessor.java:102)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 10080062 TypeError: Cannot find default value for object. (b7b11bfd779a718cabdce9ea9162012f.js#5)
    at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.executeScriptImpl(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:516)
    at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:198)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find default value for object. (b7b11bfd779a718cabdce9ea9162012f.js#5)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3350)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3340)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3356)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError1(ScriptRuntime.java:3368)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject.getDefaultValue(ScriptableObject.java:758)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject.getDefaultValue(ScriptableObject.java:677)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.toString(ScriptRuntime.java:707)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaObject.coerceTypeImpl(NativeJavaObject.java:633)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.jsToJava(Context.java:1705)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:209)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:66)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c19._c0(b7b11bfd779a718cabdce9ea9162012f.js:5)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c19.call(b7b11bfd779a718cabdce9ea9162012f.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:393)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2834)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c19.call(b7b11bfd779a718cabdce9ea9162012f.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c19.exec(b7b11bfd779a718cabdce9ea9162012f.js)
    at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.executeScriptImpl(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:492)
```

**Test 2**

```
var jsonString = "{'test': 'test'}"; 
logger.log( jsonUtils.toObject(jsonString) );
```

Error:

```
500 Internal Error
An error inside the HTTP server which prevented it from fulfilling the request.
10080036 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 10080132 Failed to execute script 'Javascript Console Script': null

org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException: 10080037 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 10080138 Failed to execute script 'Javascript Console Script': null
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:1067)
    at de.fme.jsconsole.ExecuteWebscript.executeScriptContent(Unknown Source)
    at de.fme.jsconsole.ExecuteWebscript.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at de.fme.jsconsole.ExecuteWebscript$2.execute(Unknown Source)
    at de.fme.jsconsole.ExecuteWebscript$2.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:401)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:291)
    at de.fme.jsconsole.ExecuteWebscript.runWithTransactionIfNeeded(Unknown Source)
    at de.fme.jsconsole.ExecuteWebscript.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at de.fme.jsconsole.ExecuteWebscript$1.doWork(Unknown Source)
    at de.fme.jsconsole.ExecuteWebscript$1.doWork(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:529)
    at de.fme.jsconsole.ExecuteWebscript.runScriptWithTransactionAndAuthentication(Unknown Source)
    at de.fme.jsconsole.ExecuteWebscript.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:365)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:517)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:333)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:377)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:132)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:465)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.alfresco.scripts.ScriptException: 10080138 Failed to execute script 'Javascript Console Script': null
    at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:202)
    at org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.execute(ScriptServiceImpl.java:212)
    at org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.executeScript(ScriptServiceImpl.java:174)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryScriptProcessor.executeScript(RepositoryScriptProcessor.java:102)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.json.JSONUtils.toObject(JSONUtils.java:138)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.json.JSONUtils.toObject(JSONUtils.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor582.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:155)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:243)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:66)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c48._c0(9070d44753d964f375056b15cfef5a86.js:7)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c48.call(9070d44753d964f375056b15cfef5a86.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:393)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2834)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c48.call(9070d44753d964f375056b15cfef5a86.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c48.exec(9070d44753d964f375056b15cfef5a86.js)
    at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.executeScriptImpl(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:492)
    at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:198)
    ... 39 more
```

**Test 3**

```
var jsonString = {'test': 'test'};
logger.log( jsonUtils.toObject(jsonString) );
```

Error:

```
500 Internal Error
An error inside the HTTP server which prevented it from fulfilling the request.
10080041 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 10080162 Failed to execute script 'Javascript Console Script': null
```

Comment: Have you applied any fixes for method overloading? IIRC, there's a bug in the default Rhino JS install when it comes to two methods with the same name, but different parameters

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks for the hint. No I haven't applied any fix yet, I will take a look.

Comment: Can you also clarify why you want to do this? Only if you have JSON that you want to access from within JavaScript code, what you're currently doing isn't really the best way to do that...

Comment: I want to parse json in a custom Admin console component, which is fetched from a web service, with the tools that Alfresco provides. Afaik this would be the http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.enterprise.doc%2Freferences%2Fapi-ws-obj-jsonUtils.html utility class.

Comment: If you're in JavaScript, what's wrong with simply using `eval` just as you would do client side?

Comment: @Gagravarr Nothing wrong with eval in my case actually, and eval works fine; I was just going through the Alfresco docs and trying some code in the javascript console to get to know about the Alfresco script API a bit more, when I noticed the issue described above.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you write a web script containing the same code? If not, then that would imply a problem with the JS Console, and you should raise a bug there if it reproduces with the latest code.

Comment: @WillAbson Yes, happens as well in a web script run outside the JS Console.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use single quotes inside your JSON string, you must use double-quotes. So your code in *Test 1* above should work inside a web script that you run outside of the console.

```
var jsonString = '{"test": "test"}';
logger.log( jsonUtils.toObject(jsonString) );
```

You still get an exception being thrown when this same code is run inside the console, i.e.

> 10080062 TypeError: Cannot find default value for object. (b7b11bfd779a718cabdce9ea9162012f.js#5)

This looks specific to the [JavaScript console](https://github.com/share-extras/js-console), so please [raise an issue](https://github.com/share-extras/js-console/issues) there.

Oh, and obviously you can continue to use `eval()` in the meantime. If you're fetching data from an Alfresco source or one that you control then this is relatively safe.

Comment: "This looks specific to the JavaScript console, so please raise an issue there." --> it also happens as well in a web script run outside the JS Console. I think the reason is @Gagravarr's first comment above.